# Django - Room model needs to have a selection of many room types. One room must have at least one room type from the predefined selection

Tags: django, python-2.7, sqlite, django-rest-framework

**Room not saving to the database, and how can I improve this? Is there a better way?**

One property can have one or many rooms. One room must belong to one property.

I start by creating the Room Model

```
class Room(models.Model):
  property = models.ForeignKey(Property)

  name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

  description = models.TextField(max_length=800)

  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='room_images/', blank=False)

  bar_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False)

  max_occupancy = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=False)

  extra_beds = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)

  price_per_exra_bed = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)

  is_breakfast_included = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  room_type_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False)

  ROOM_TYPES = (
    ('SGL', 'Single'),
    ('TWN', 'Twin'),
    ('DBL', 'Double'),
    ('TRPL', 'Triple'),
    ('STND', 'Standard'),
    ('DLX', 'Deluxe'),
    ('EXET', 'Executive'),
    ('SPR', 'Superior'),
    ('JS', 'Junior Suite'),
    ('ONEBDR', 'One Bedroom'),
    ('TWOBDR', 'Two Bedroom'),
    ('THREEBDR', 'Three Bedroom'),
    ('FOURBDR', 'Four Bedroom'),
    ('FIVEBDR', 'Five Bedroom'),
    ('SIXBDR', 'Six Bedroom'),
    ('SEVENBDR', 'Seven Bedroom'),
   )
  room_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ROOM_TYPES, default="STND")


def __str__(self):
  return self.name
```

I create a new form to allow the user to fill out the form. Inside forms.py

```
class RoomForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Room
    exclude = ("property",)
```

As you can see above I exclude the property model, I don’t need to add the property info into the RoomForm.

In views.py I have modified the property_add_room function to save the room into the database:

```
@login_required(login_url='/property/sign-in/')
def property_add_room(request):
  form = RoomForm()

  if request.method == "POST":
    form = RoomForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
      room = form.save(commit=False)
      room.property = request.user.property
      room.save()
      return redirect(property_room)

  return render(request, 'property/add_room.html', {
     "form": form
  })
```

Here is the property model. The user has one property and one property must belong to one user.

```
class Property(models.Model):
 user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='property')
 name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
 phone = models.CharField(max_length=500)
 address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
 total_rooms = models.CharField(max_length=500)
 logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='property_logo/', blank=False)
```

Comment: What is the question? And why `room.property = request.user.property`?

Comment: Does the user definitely have a `property` associated with it?

Comment: @BidhanMajhi With room.property I am assigning the property to the room object, and with  request.user.property to return to the property that the current user is signed in to.

RHSmith159  Yes each user has one property and one property belongs to one user. Initially when a user signs up, they fill out a form and inside that form is the UserForm and the PropertyForm. Once they submit the property is created.


I have updated the question and added the property model. Yes the user definitely is associated with the property.

Comment: Your property model is an extend of user model. Are you sure if you want an OneonOne field there? If yes, then you can use User instead of Property in the Foreign key inside Room model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your Room model. Also your property will be deleted if the user is deleted. Are you sure you want this?

```
class Room(models.Model):
  property = models.ForeignKey(Property)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  description = models.TextField(max_length=800)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='room_images/', blank=False)
  bar_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False)

  SGL = 1
  TWN = 2
  DBL = 3
  TRPL = 4
  STND = 5
  DLX = 6
  EXET = 7
  SPR = 8
  SPR = 9
  JS = 10
  ONEBDR = 11
  TWOBDR = 12
  THREEBDR = 13
  FOURBDR = 14
  FIVEBDR = 15
  SIXBDR = 16
  SEVENBDR = 17

  ROOM_TYPES = (
    (SGL, 'Single'),
    (TWN, 'Twin'),
    (DBL, 'Double'),
    (TRPL, 'Triple'),
    (STND, 'Standard'),
    (DLX, 'Deluxe'),
    (EXET, 'Executive'),
    (SPR, 'Superior'),
    (JS, 'Junior Suite'),
    (ONEBDR, 'One Bedroom'),
    (TWOBDR, 'Two Bedroom'),
    (THREEBDR, 'Three Bedroom'),
    (FOURBDR, 'Four Bedroom'),
    (FIVEBDR, 'Five Bedroom'),
    (SIXBDR, 'Six Bedroom'),
    (SEVENBDR, 'Seven Bedroom'),
  )
  room_type = models.IntegerField(choices=ROOM_TYPES)
  max_occupancy = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=False)
  extra_beds = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
  price_per_exra_bed = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
  is_breakfast_included = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  room_type_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```